# Express centroid of 3 pts in point + vector notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, affine-geometry, centroid

Given 3 points `(A, B, and C)`, express their centroid `P` in point+vector notation `P = Q + sV`.

I know the centroid of three points is

$$(A + B + C) \cdot (1/3)$$

but I'm unsure how to get that into something with a vector.

I'd appreciate any and all help.

**Edit:** I don't believe `s` has to be in the answer, because then it would be a line.

Comment: Your so-called point+vector notation appears to represent a line not a point if $s$ is a parameter, whereas the centroid is just a single point.

Comment: You're correct. I don't think we need to have `s` in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is just to pick one of the points to be your starting point (basically your origin) and then represent each of the other points wrt that origin:

$$\begin{align}\frac 13A + \frac 13B + \frac 13C &= \frac 13A + \frac 13(A + (B-A)) + \frac 13(A+(C-A)) \\ &= A + \frac 13(B - A) + \frac 13(C-A) \\ &= A + \frac 13(\vec {AB} + \vec {AC})\end{align}$$

Once you get used to converting between barycentric and $P+\vec v$ forms this becomes second nature and you'll be able to do it in one step.